# Apache Airflow SqlSensor MSSQL issues on Docker running on Windows 10

Tags: python, docker, airflow, pymssql

I'm trying to run the SqlSensor locally under docker on a Windows 10 machine, it runs on Linux but get below errors when trying to run the same simple DAG locally.

The reason I'm trying to set this up is so that I can develop locally and test to speed up the development cycle.

Error from Airflow log:

```
[2018-05-22 08:27:04,929] {{models.py:1428}} INFO - Executing <Task(SqlSensor): limits_test> on 2018-05-21 08:00:00
[2018-05-22 08:27:04,929] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run sql-sensor-test-dag limits_test 2018-05-21T08:00:00 --job_id 8 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/sql_sensor_test.py']
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,685] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-05-22 08:27:05,684] {{__init__.py:45}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,749] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-05-22 08:27:05,749] {{models.py:189}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/sql_sensor_test.py
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,791] {{cli.py:374}} INFO - Running on host 0f8e7a60dbab
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,858] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-05-22 08:27:05,858] {{base_hook.py:80}} INFO - Using connection to: LABCHGVA-SQL295
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,888] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-05-22 08:27:05,888] {{sensors.py:111}} INFO - Poking: SELECT max(snapshot_id) FROM limits_run
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,896] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-05-22 08:27:05,896] {{base_hook.py:80}} INFO - Using connection to: LABCHGVA-SQL295
[2018-05-22 08:27:05,924] {{models.py:1595}} ERROR - Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 638, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:6594)
_mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/sensors.py", line 78, in execute
    while not self.poke(context):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/sensors.py", line 112, in poke
    records = hook.get_records(self.sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 106, in get_records
    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/mssql_hook.py", line 43, in get_conn
    port=conn.port)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 644, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10892)
pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
```

Using this Docker image:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.9.0-2

USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install freetds-dev -yqq && \
 pip install apache-airflow[mssql]

USER airflow
```

And the following simple DAG:

```
from datetime import timedelta

import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import SqlSensor

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catchup': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'email': ['myemail@company.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 10,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15),
    'sla': timedelta(hours=3)
}

dag = DAG(
    'sql-sensor-test-dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Sensor tests',
    schedule_interval='0 8 * * *'
    # schedule_interval='@once'
)

with dag:
    sql_sensor = SqlSensor(
        task_id='limits_test',
        conn_id='bpeak_limits_ro',
        sql="SELECT max(snapshot_id) FROM limits_run"
    )

    done = DummyOperator(task_id='done')

    sql_sensor >> done
```

Comment: The error says that you can't connect to the database server. What does your connection string look like? If the database isn't inside the container, did you configure connectivity to the host?

Comment: You're right!
I've tested by installing ping and spinning up a new separate container locally and that works just fine. 
Now I just need to figure where in ports gets restricted, perhaps docker compose : )

Thanks again,